# exception exception in module wampmanager.exe at 000f15a0

Tags: wamp

I installed the wamp.when I run it shows this error "exception exception in module wampmanager.exe at 000f15a0 ". I googled and  installed The Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)  and The Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) but the problem  not solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved! I had installed wamp64 on 32bit system!